# insert mongo document field only when it's missing

Tags: mongodb

Novice question:

I have a mongo collection that was created before.  Some recent documents have been inserted but the structure slightly changes -- only new fields were added.  Now I'd like to go back and update the old documents with the new fields with a default value.  How?

Example:

```
db.testme.insert({x:0, y:1})
db.testme.insert({x:1, y:1})
db.testme.insert({x:0, y:1, z:2})
db.testme.find()
```

How do I update the first two documents with "z" value of zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [**`$set`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator in your update, with a query that looks for documents that do not have the z field (using [**`$exists`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator). The following update operator
demonstrates this:

```
db.testme.update(
    { "z": { "$exists": false } },
    { "$set": { "z": 0 } },
    { "multi": true }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this was useful. Just wondering, is there a way this can be done with all the values that do not exist inside a collection (update a collection to the most recent schema)?